# Given a piece of text tokenize location text

Tags: location, nltk

I am trying to see if there is a handy Python library that can take a string and return indexes of words that represent a location?

Example:

Input text: "New York is a state in United States"

Returns tokens: New York, United States

Or their respective indices in text.

I want to use it to highlight locations in display text automatically in my website.

Answer (score 1):

SpaCy is the library to use for this task.

You should install `en_core_web_lg` (the largest English model) for the best Named Entity Recognition (NER) accuracy.

Then run the below code to collect location entities.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')
text = "New York is a state in United States"
doc = nlp(text)
# GPE = Countries, cities, states, LOC = Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water
locations = [ent for ent in doc.ents if ent.label_ in ['GPE', 'LOC']] 
print(locations)
```

Output:

```
[New York, United States]
```